# Where should put all the php project in Xampp server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, xampp

I'm very new to `XAMPP` and now trying to send `SQLite` data from android to `MySQL`. I've been reading  many tutorials and this is  one of the [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) I read.

The article using `Wamp` server and located all the file.php in `C:/wamp/www`. I using XAMPP server and can't find the `www` folder. Which folder should I put all the .php file ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all PHP files should be put on:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs
```

Or you may set to your own location in `httpd.conf` by:

```
DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs"  --> This htdocs is in my drive D:
```

Comment: Thanks. If I have 5 tables in SQLite, I  need to create 5 tables in MySQL ?

Comment: can you help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469430/fail-to-do-registration-using-php-mysql-and-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Hello your path is : `C:\xampp\htdocs\your_project_name\`
and the path to that is `http:\\localhost\your_project_name\`.
Goodluck

Answer (score 1):

Default directory: /xampp/htdocs/

 You can change it from httpd.conf file: DocumentRoot "your/path/"